# Novell Client logout with windows logoff

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, novell, logoff

I have a windows 2008 R2 server that's running the Novell Client 2 SP2. I noticed that when I remote in to the system and then logoff of my remote session the Novell client also logs out. Is there a way to prevent the client from logging out as I have scripts running on the server which are expecting to see the proper drives mounted by the Novell client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The client is running under your user/security context, and when you logoff, your user context goes away... along anything running in it.

The only solution to this is to not log off.  If you disconnect the remote session, instead of logging off, your sessions, and anything running it, continue to run.

Comment: That's what I figured, is there a way to mount them as a daemon process so that users logging in/out wont cause this problem?

Comment: @LF4 I imagine so... at least in theory, you can have anything run as a system service, without any user context, but it's not trivial to convert an existing application or service into this mode - Domino Server, for example, (as of version 8) still needs to be run under a user context, and if it was easy to do, you'd think IBM would have done it by now.